# Breaking the AC barrier using Kelley-Morse set theory

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, large-cardinals

In her blog post [*Variants of Kelley-Morse set theory*](http://boolesrings.org/victoriagitman/2014/02/24/variants-of-kelley-morse-set-theory/), Prof. Gitman proves that every model of the the common version of Kelley-Morse set theory ($\mathsf{KM}$) is a model of the [Wikipedia version of $\mathsf{KM}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory) and conversely.  While this is an interesting result in its own right, her presentation of the "common version" of $\mathsf{KM}$ leads me to ask the following question:

Can $\mathsf{KM}$ set theory as it stands allow us to break through the $\mathsf{AC}$ barrier (the $\mathsf{AC}$ barrier—that is, $\mathsf{AC}$ itself—is what allegedly forbids the existence of [Reinhardt cardinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhardt_cardinal) to exist via the [Kunen inconsistency theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunen%27s_inconsistency_theorem)).

Clearly, $\mathsf{KM}$ set theory is important for the proof of the Kunen inconsistency; the Kunen inconsistency, as Kunen actually stated in his paper is

> If $j$ is an elementary embedding from $V$ into $V$, $j$ is the identity.

As has been stated by the authors of *Generalizations of the Kunen Inconsistency* (Annals of Pure and Applied Logic, vol.163, No.12, pp.1872–1890, [doi:10.1016/j.apal.2012.06.001](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2012.06.001), [arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1951)) and *The Role of the Foundation Axiom in the Kunen Inconsistency* ([arXiv link](http://xxx.tau.ac.il/abs/1311.0814v1)), $\mathsf{KM}$ is the only set theory in which the Kunen inconsistency can be properly stated, because it is only in $\mathsf{KM}$ that one can prove the existence of a full satisfaction class for first-order truth, making the assertion "$j$ is elementary" expressible in $\mathsf{KM}$.

With this in mind, let me restate the "common version" of $\mathsf{KM}$ as given in Prof. Gitman's blog post, for reference:

> The axioms for sets are Extensionality, Pairing, Infinity, Union, Powerset, Regularity.  The axioms for classes are:
>
> 1. **Extensionality**
> 2. **Full Class Comprehension:**  If $\phi$(x) is any formula in the two-sorted language [one sort for sets, one sort for classes—my comment] with class parameters, then the collection of all those sets such that $\phi$(x) holds is a class.
> 3. **Replacement:**  If $F$ is a class function and $a$ is a set, then the range of $F|a$ is a set.
> 4. **Global well-order:**  there is a 1-1 and onto class function $\phi: \mathrm{ORD} \to  V$.  [Question: do class axioms (3) and (4) imply that every set can be well-ordered?]

The following question (at least to me) immediately presents itself:

Does class axiom (4) (provided it well-orders $V$) imply the Kunen inconsistency?  If so, then it certainly does not provide a means for surmounting the $AC$ barrier.

In order to remedy that situation, one could always weaken (4) in the following fashion:

> 4'.  There is a 1-1 class function $\phi : \mathrm{ORD} \to V$.  Let there be a proper subclass $U$ of $V$ such that $\phi : \mathrm{ORD} \to U$ be 1-1 and onto, but there are no bijections from $ORD$ to $V$ .

Indeed, if one is a believer is the set-theoretic multiverse, there are models of $\mathsf{KM}{-}(4){+}(4')$ in which $U$ is countable.  The question that remains, however, is whether (4) is needed to make "$j$ is elementary" expressible in $\mathsf{KM}$.

Comment: What is "the AC barrier"?

Comment: The formulation of $4'$ is really just saying that global choice fails, and nothing more. As I remarked in my answer, the existence of such $U$ is trivial, e.g. the class of ordinals and the identity function.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  What if one replaces (4) with the following (possibly silly--you tell me) axiom: (4'') '$V$ is amorphous'?

Comment: Then one easily arrives to a contradiction, since the ordinals witness otherwise. (I am assuming you mean amorphous in the sense that the universe cannot be partitioned into two proper classes. If you mean two infinite sets, $\omega$ is enough.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  OK.  Thanks.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  Are you saying that there has been little or no progress towards a resolution of this problem?  Perhaps you could revise your answer and tell me ( and others) what the 'roadblocks' are to a solution to the problem (either way--either in showing in $KM$ without $Global$ $well order$ that there can exist nontrivial elementary embeddings from $V$ into $V$; or that the Kunen inconsistency can be proven in $KM$ without $Global$ $wellorder$).  I would be happy to accept an answer that could at least try to answer that for me.

Comment: The only roadblock I can think of, is that we cannot prove this, so the problem is "did we find a refutation yet?" and so far we have no idea where it might be. So proving that something like that exists is flat out impossible; the best we can do is try and refute this. So far, efforts are unsuccessful. You probably read more papers by Koellner and Woodin on the topic than I have, so you probably have a better clue than me.

Answer (score 1):

Something is not clear to me about your question.

1. Global choice implies the axiom of choice for sets. Of course it does. Every set is a subclass of $V$, and if $V$ can be well-ordered, then every set can be well-ordered.
2. Requiring that there is an injection from the class of ordinals into $V$ is provable in $\sf ZF$. This function is the identity function. If you wish for something less trivial, $\alpha\mapsto V_\alpha$ is also an option.
3. Expressing "elementary for sets" has nothing to do with the axiom of choice.

Comment: Regarding (2) of your answer, what I am trying to convey is that $V$ goes beyond sets of ordinals, i.e. beyond the iterative hierarchy.  Have you an idea on how best to express this (since you have dealt with 'choiceless' models of $ZF$ )?  This is what I believe is meant  by going beyond the '$AC$ barrier' (the phrase was coined by Peter Koellner, so perhaps you should take a look at some of his papers referring to that).

Comment: Going beyond sets of ordinals is fine. The universe of $\sf ZF+\lnot AC$ usually has much more information (meaning the sets of ordinals need not fully encode of the entire model like the do with models of $\sf ZFC$). But it doesn't meant that $V$ is the the limit of the von Neumann hierarchy.

Comment: Are there models of $ZF+{\lnot}AC$ that have Reinhardt cardinals?  If not, what keeps these models from having them?  I have been reading a couple of Reinhardt's papers and at the time he wrote them, he believed models of $ZF+AD$ might have Reinhardt cardinals.

Comment: Thomas, since you are so familiar with Koellner's work you should know that whether or not it is possible to have Reinhardt cardinals in $\sf ZF$ is open. And since $\sf ZF+AD$ is equiconsistent with just $\sf ZFC$+infinitely many Woodin cardinals, I think it's safe to say Reinhardt was wrong about that.